# View static field values in dnSpy

Tags: debugging, .net

I'm using dnSpy (version: 4.5.3) to debug a .NET binary. I can successfully view the values of Local variables in the Locals window but I cannot view the values of static fields.

However, per this github discussion: https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/issues/334 for dnSpy, this feature was already added in version 4.0

Please refer the image below. The locals windows doesn't show the value of Static Fields.

[image]

Is there a way to view them? How can I use the C# Interactive feature of dnSpy to view these values?

Thanks.

Comment: it says on the screen, decompiler generated values can't be evaluated. There's nothing about it being static or not